# EVP_EncryptUpdate, input size must be multiple of 16

Tags: openssl, size, buffer

I'am working with OpenSSL and evp. My problem is, when I call `EVP_EncryptUpdate`, with an input size, that is not a multiple of 16, the function is deleting the rest characters.

Here's my code:

```
string a = "hello";

int ilen;

unsigned char * outbuf = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH);
unsigned char * inbuff = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 1024);

for (int i = 0; i < a.size (); i++)
     inbuff[i] = a[i];

EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &ilen, inbuff, strlen (inbuff));
```

Here, `ilen` will be 0, but if i call it, with an input size of 16, it returns 16, too.

What can I do to encrypt everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ...with an input size, that is not a multiple of 16,
> the function is deleting the rest characters...
> ... ilen will be 0, but if i call it, with an input
> size of 16, it returns 16...
> ```

AES's block size is 16 bytes. If you insert 1,3,5 etc bytes, the bytes are buffered until 16 are available. Once 16 are input, the block can be encrypted and passed back out to the caller.

If you insert 16 bytes, then there are enough bytes to encrypt a block and pass it back to the caller.

If you only insert 5 or so bytes and then call `EVP_EncryptFinal`, then the cipher object will pad to a full block. After padding and encryption, the last block (or two) is passed back to the caller.

The buffered bytes are held in the context object.

If you are "losing" bytes, then you are doing something wrong. Maybe you are overwriting something with a memory error; or maybe you are not calling `EVP_EncryptFinal`.

---

> What can I do to encrypt everything?

Be sure to check return values, and be sure to sum the bytes written:

```
int written = 0, temp;

rc = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ..., &temp, ..., ...);
written += temp;

// Repeat calls to EVP_EncryptUpdate

rc = EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, ..., &temp);
written += temp;
```

Mine usually looks something like:

```
int written = 0, temp;
unsigned char * outbuf = ...;

rc = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, &outbuf[written], &temp, inbuf, insize);
assert(rc == 1);
written += temp;

// Repeat calls to EVP_EncryptUpdate

rc = EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, &outbuf[written], &temp);
assert(rc == 1);
written += temp;
```

After `EVP_EncryptFinal`, `written` bytes are available in `outbuf`.

I believe you can pass also `NULL` for `outbuf` and retrieve everything on the call to final:

```
int written = 0, temp;
unsigned char * outbuf = ...;

rc = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, NULL, inbuf, insize);
assert(rc == 1);

// Repeat calls to EVP_EncryptUpdate

rc = EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, outbuf, &written);
assert(rc == 1);
```

Comment: You can't do the last one (passing NULLs), with the current OpenSSL version (1.0.2). You'd get memory access violation errors.